# Possibly a late 70's Animated sci-fi show with *one* episode about a meat eating venus fly trap growing huge and becoming dangerous?

Tags: story-identification, animation

I found a show that looks somewhat (very) similar in style: It is called *Kidd Video*. I don't think it's the right show but it has a lot of very similar elements in world design if you can call it that.

---

I saw this at 1986~ on VHS. It was in English. It might be a "very" old anime? That is the general look I remember more or less but it also resembles 70's sci fi US animations so... (and it was English dubbed).

[image: Anime age looks]

It was an animated show with somewhat anatomically proportionate human (I think white young adult) characters. In one episode (I think) a girl is feeding a plant with (maybe) meat balls until it grows out of control and becomes too dangerous. Then they somehow solve this.

I think this episode took place around their home or a restaurant. It looked very futuristic. The characters looked anatomically proportionate and the ambiance was not dismal or glum. It was like a happy sci-fi/fantasy ambiance. I guess you could say it was more of a futuristic fantasy vibe.

In another episode I remember a futuristic looking room with tiny flying discs or saucers and the characters needed to jump between them (or something).

I think there were at least three characters and at least one of the is a girl?

We had this on VHS.

It is possible that it doesn't take lace on Earth but if it does, it's in the future.

Comment: Any chance this wasn't a cartoon and was [_Little Shop of Horrors_](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QqFZuR6UzjA)?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot It was an animated sci-fi series and only one episode had a creature similar to the venus fly trap from Little Shop.

Comment: That was a fairly common plot though. I remember at least He-Man doing it, I'm sure there were others.

Comment: @DanielRoseman
I guess you are right!
I looked here:
https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ManEatingPlant
But did not find anything.
The only other part I remember is a room with indoor flying disc or saucers that they needed to jump on as part of their adventure.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tlz1Ut-5gN0
I recommend using this video to help yourself find your show if you are looking. It is pretty comprehensive.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest this could be either an episode of The Space Sentinels shown on British TV in the late 1970s and early 80s or an episode of Battle of the Planets.

The space sentinels had a cast of three main characters. One was a girl and there was definetly an episode revolving around plants growing out of control. Memory does not allow me to be more detailed than that sadly.

The Battle of the planets episode sounds more likely to me though. It was a Japanese anime, original title being Gatchaman. Th episode with the plants is actually a two parter called Fierce Flowers (Attack of the Jigo Killers in the original Japanese). The plants are vaguely Venus fly trap shaped, one character is female and does own a restaurant although this is peripheral to the story. I will update this answer with links if I can find the relevant clips on YouTube

Comment: This is a pretty good answer because I considered it could be one of these shows during my research. They certainly look the part but the characters didn't have any super powers so I don't think it was Sentinels.

Comment: I do think the characters may have had similar visors. I clearly remember one of the characters "over" feeding a small plant until it becomes big and dangerous.

Comment: If anyone wants to check out "Fierce Flowers", I found it here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6G5ydcnQxv4
It is not the one I was looking for but indeed highly accurate considering the description so it may help someone else.

Comment: One thing I could say is that the show I was writing about has more of a "happy colorful" vibe. Also, thank you kindly for the help. :)

Comment: Sorry to hear it wasn't either of those. Here is another possibility. Thunderbirds 2086 episode called Kudzilla. Its an anime inspired update of Thunderbirds and aired in about 1982. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sEYLpSs67p8 there is a scene with a plant  being fed and growing out of control starting at about the 3 minute mark.

Comment: I can't seem to reply to you. Anyhow, good try and might help many others with this question. :) It is amazing how often this was used. The plant in that show had a thing like a head (I guess). I am also pretty sure that it was hand fed and was a potted plant at first.